# Scoping Queries within Trait on a Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, oop, model, traits

## A Little Background…

I have two models within my application that are 'locatable'. I could very easily write a query in a repository to return what I need, however, I am sure this can be done much better with the help of Laravel Scopes and Traits etc (I may be wrong).

So, I have come up with the following solution:

### Example Abstract Model

```
abstract class AbstractModel extends Model implements SomeOtherStuff     
{
    public function scopeNearby(Builder $query)     
    {
        return $query->selectRaw('
                (
                    6373000 * acos(
                        cos( radians( ' . $this->location->latitude . ' ) )     
                        * cos( radians( X(' . $this->location->table . '.location) ) )     
                        * cos( radians( Y(' . $this->location->table . '.location) ) - radians( ' . $this->location->longitude . ' ) )     
                        + sin( radians( ' . $this->location->latitude . ' ) )
                        * sin( radians( X(' . $this->location->table . '.location) ) )
                    )
                ) AS distance
           ')
            // I wanted to use ->with('location') below instead of ->join() but it didn’t work
            ->join($this->location->table, $this->location->primaryKey, '=', $this->primaryKey);
    }

    // All other Abstract stuff here
}
```

### Example User Model

```
class User extends AbstractModel implements SomeOtherStuff
{     
    /**
     * Get the location of the user.     
     */
    public function location()
    {     
        return $this->hasOne(‘App\Models\User\Location', 'user_id');     
    }

    // All other model stuff here
}
```

### Example User Controller

```
class UserController extends AbstractController     
{
    /**
     * Return the nearby users.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */     
    public function nearby()
    {
        $users = $this->shield->user()->nearby()->toSql();

        // Print out the query to ensure it is structured correctly
        echo $users;     
    }
}
```

## My Issues

The above solution works, however, it is very wrong (in my opinion)! The `nearby()` scope should only be available to models that are ‘locatable’. Naturally, I thought the best solution was to implement a Trait like so:

```
trait Locatable
{
    /**         
     * Scope a query to include the distance from the current model.         
     *
     * @param   \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder         
     */         
    public function scopeNearby(Builder $query)         
    {
        // Same as above implementation     
    }     
}
```

The problem with this is that the properties of the model that I need are `protected` and therefore not accessible via a Trait…

## My Question(s)

Assuming the above makes sense, please see my questions below:

1. Is there a better way to implement this desired functionality and if so, please can someone point me in the right direction?
2. This is lower priority but why does `->with('location')` not work? Am I using it wrong? I expected it to add an inner join to the query but it didn’t…

Comment: Properties of the model that you need as in? Can you please name them? Are you talking about `primary_key` etc?

Comment: @prateekkathal Yes, as in the ones listed in the `scopeNearby()` method. e.g. `$this->location->latitude`, `$this->location->longitude`, `$this->location->table`, `$this->location->primaryKey`, `$this->primaryKey`

Comment: You can get the table name by `getTable()` and primaryKey by `getKey()` methods. Why is latitude, longitude protected?

Comment: @prateekkathal Sorry, latitude and longitude are not protected. I didnt know the `getKey()` and `getTable()` methods existed! haha! Thank you very much!! Apart from the fact that you have solved the issue, what are your thoughts on the proposed structure?

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be done actually

```
trait Locatable {

  /**
   * Scope a query to include the distance from the current model.
   *
   * @param   \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
   */
  public function scopeNearby($query)
  {
    if(!$this->location) {
      return $query;
    }

    return $query->whereHas('location',
      function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('
                    //Your query for distance (Use the getTable() function wherever required...)
                  ) AS distance
                ')
              ->having('distance', '<', 25);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer to your questions.

1. The above is the better approach. You should use `whereHas()` for relational queries.
2. With query will not work because with doesn't join the tables, it only does a WHERE EXISTS () query and then later adds it as a relation to the model returned. To know more... What you can do is....

(Write this wherever you want in your controller... just for the purpose of testing)

```
dd($user->with('locations')->toSql());
```

Let me know if you face any issues... :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Learned a lot!! :-D

Comment: Sorry Prateek, I have just noticed an issue with the above. If I actually wanted to return the value of 'distance', how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @BenCarey I didn't know distance was required to be selected.... We will have to make join for such purposes... May I know if I distance is required for all users returned or only one of them? Because if it is required in only one case, you can also use simple PHP to calculate the distance.

Comment: The distance is required for every row returned unfortunately, thats why I originally had a join :-(

Comment: In that case, you can use the function that you were using earlier... Because `whereHas()` limits the query to `WHERE EXISTS ()` in **sql**.

Comment: @BenCarey Let me know if anything else is required. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130244/discussion-between-ben-carey-and-prateekkathal).